# Using switch to access weather icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, icons

I'm trying to use a switch statement to access the icons from https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/ with the http://simpleweatherjs.com/ API.

I think I have everything set up correctly - I have the weather-icons.css file in my CSS folder and I copied the font folder over as well.

When I console.log the code below, it only returns the default "thermometer-exterior" case.

```
function getTemp(currentLat,currentLong) {
  var getURL = 'https://simple-weather.p.mashape.com/weatherdata?lat=' + currentLat +'&lng=' + currentLong + '&deg=F';

$.ajax({
headers: {
  "X-Mashape-Key": "2lp07ix0Wbmshx4DT1QG8ZuPr3Ynp15ZORmjsnRTWmCuVL8gO1"
},
url: getURL,
success: function(response) {
  var json_obj = JSON.parse(response);
  var current = json_obj.query.results.channel.item;
  var temp = current.condition.temp;
  var condIcon = current.condition.code;
  var description = current.condition.text;
  var units = json_obj.query.results.channel.units;
  console.log(current);

  $(".temp").html(temp + ' ' + units.temperature);
  $(".description").html(description);

  switch (condIcon) {
    case 0:
      condIcon = 'tornado';
      break;

    case 1:
    case 2:
      condIcon = 'hurricane';
      break;

    case 3:
    case 4:
      condIcon = 'day-thunderstorm';
      break;

    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
      condIcon = 'rain-mix';
      break;

    case 8:
    case 9:
      condIcon = 'showers';
      break;

    case 10:
    case 11:
    case 12:
      condIcon = 'rain';
      break;

    case 13:
    case 14:
    case 15:
    case 16:
      condIcon = 'snow';
      break;

    case 17:
    case 18:
      condIcon = 'hail';
      break;

    case 19:
      condIcon = 'dust';
      break;

    case 20:
    case 21:
      condIcon = 'fog';
      break;

    case 22:
      condIcon = 'smoke';
      break;

    case 23:
    case 24:
      condIcon = 'windy';
      break;

    case 25:
      condIcon = 'snowflake-cold';
      break;

    case 26:
      condIcon = 'cloudy';
      break;

    case 27:
    case 29:
      condIcon = 'night-cloudy';
      break;

    case 28:
    case 30:
      condIcon = 'day-cloudy';
      break;

    case 31:
      condIcon = 'night-clear';
      break;

    case 32:
      condIcon = 'day-sunny';
      break;

    case 33:
      condIcon = 'stars';
      break;

    case 34:
      condIcon = 'sunny';
      break;

    case 35:
      condIcon = 'rain-mix';
      break;

    case 36:
      condIcon = 'hot';
      break;

    case 37:
    case 38:
    case 39:
      condIcon = 'thunderstorm';
      break;

    case 40:
      condIcon = 'sprinkles';
      break;

    case 41:
    case 42:
      condIcon = 'snow';
      break;

    case 44:
      condIcon = 'day-cloudy';
      break;

    case 45:
      condIcon = 'thundershower';
      break;

    case 46:
      condIcon = 'snow';
      break;

    case 47:
      condIcon = 'storm-showers';
      break;

    case 3200:
      condIcon = 'thermometer-exterior';
      break;

    default:
      condIcon = 'thermometer-exterior';
}

// add the css prefix
condIcon = 'wi-' + condIcon;

// set the image
console.log(condIcon);
$('.icon i').addClass('wi').addClass(condIcon);
}
  });
}
```

What's going on here? The API is returning the correct weather code - is it my switch statement? I'm also not seeing the icon when my page loads. Here's the html -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/weather.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/weather.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-12"><p>Local Weather</p></div>
    </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12"><p class="location"></p></div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><p class="description"></p></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> <p class="temp"></p></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> <p class="icon"></p></div>
   <div class="row">

   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Console.log condIcon right before your switch statement to see what values you are getting

Comment: It gives the correct weather code. For example, right now I get 33 for "night-partly-cloudy"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the condIcon value is not a string, try using

```
condIcon = parseInt(current.condition.code);
```

Comment: I tested this out and can confirm that this is the issue.

Comment: Also I wanted to edit your answer but I can't becuase the edit is too small, but I think it would also be better to include the radix, so `condIcon = parseInt(current.condition.code, 10)` ... although it will normally be in base10 anyway, just to be sure it's good to include as best practice.